# Excel to return matched value in rows from a column array

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, array

Super stumped, I am trying to return the values of column based on the value of a cell found in a number of columns. I have attached an image to better describe what I mean. [Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYksJ.jpg) So, I'd like to populate column N with each unique value in column M when it finds the value of cell N1. So in cell N1, return row N4 where LICS was found in the array A4 to M27, what I would expect to see is in column O, I am having a dumb day so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if a MATCH is found in that row between columns A:L. If found, return column M from that row. Put this in N4 and drag it down.

```
=if(isnumber(match(n$1, a4:l4, 0)), m4, "")
```

Comment: You sir are a genius!